# Python Pandas DataFrame: Matching column names to row index'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing my raw data:

```
          Var1  Var2         Var3
0  3090.032408  18.0  1545.016204
1  3048.781680  18.0  1524.390840
2  3090.032408  18.0  1545.016204
3  3112.086341  18.0  1556.043170
4  3075.100780  16.0  1537.550390
```

And a DataFrame containing values relating to the variables in my first DataFrame:

```
      minVal  maxVal
Var1    3045    4000
Var2      15      19
Var3    1500    1583
```

For every column in `DF1`, I need to find the relating row in `DF2` in order to apply standardisation where I'm subtracting the minVal and dividing by the range. Column1 in `DF1` may not relate to row1 in `DF2` - there are more rows in `DF2` than columns in `DF1`.

How do I loop through my columns and apply standardisation in an efficient way?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show a data frame with some expected output?

Comment: The output will be a dataframe of the same size and shape as `DF1`, but each column will have been standardised and have values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Pandas' automatic index alignment, expressing this computation is remarkably easy:

```
(DF1-DF2['minVal'])/(DF2['maxVal']-DF2['minVal'])
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Var1': [3090.032408, 3048.78168, 3090.032408, 3112.086341, 3075.10078],
    'Var2': [18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0],
    'Var3': [1545.016204, 1524.39084, 1545.016204, 1556.04317, 1537.55039]})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'maxVal': [4000, 19, 1583,10], 'minVal': [3045, 15, 1500,11],
                'A':[1,2,3,12], 'B':[5,6,7,13]},
                   index=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3','Var4'])

DF3 = DF2.loc[DF1.columns, :]
result = (DF1-DF3['minVal'])/(DF3['maxVal']-DF3['minVal'])
print(result)
```

yields

```
       Var1  Var2      Var3
0  0.047154  0.75  0.542364
1  0.003960  0.75  0.293866
2  0.047154  0.75  0.542364
3  0.070247  0.75  0.675219
4  0.031519  0.25  0.452414
```

Comment: Yep, that was pretty simple! I do have more rows in `DF2` than columns in `DF1`, so I'm getting some columns of `nan`s. How should I overcome that?

Comment: You could use `DF3 = DF2.loc[DF1.columns, :]` to restrict `DF2` to just those rows whose labels match columns in `DF1`. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.

Comment: ... or you could call `result = result.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` to remove columns which are all NaNs, but that seems a bit sloppy.

Comment: Thank you, that was a massive help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to get what you want. Calculates min, max, range for each column on the fly

```
df2 = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've saved `DF2` from a training set and now I've reloaded it and want to apply the same transformations to a test set, which may have different min and max values.

Comment: gotcha. Are you using scikit-learn? if so you could fit StandardScaler() or MinMaxScaler (any scaler) on the test set and reuse again on the training set.

Comment: I was using StandardScaler, but couldn't work out how to save and reuse, hence I've just switched to doing it manually. I think I prefer it though, I have more control and can try different standardisation methods

Comment: I was just working on a similar thing. Here's what I came up with if you change your mind:

'scaler = StandardScaler()'

'scaler.fit(X_train)'
'scaler.transform(X_train)'
'scaler.transform(X_test)'

saving it as 'scaler' allows you to keep track, save multiple fit Scalers